# Cannot finish "Intermediate Construction" in Training, because engine is not available

Tags: kerbal-space-program

Just started trying out Kerbal Space Program, 1.12.3, "On Final Approach"

While working through the "Training" menu, the third installment "Intermediate Construction" immediatly started presenting some problems.

- On-screen instructions said to open the ship "Hopper" from the menu. There is no such ship in the menu.
- On-screen instructions also said "If you mess up, you can recreate the craft from the part list"

OK, so it is easy enough to recreate the Hopper from the parts list. Moving on, we soon get to where the on-screen instructions direct you to open the "Engines" tab. There is nothing in the "Engines" tab, and there is no moving forward.

Is there anything I can do?

---

*The "Swivel" engine is also required in the "Advanced Construction" training lesson, and it's not available in there either.*

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A mod has been made especially to fix the broken tutorials since 1.12.2. [You can download it here.](https://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/206198-112x-tutorial-fixes/)

Comment: Thank you! Somewhat ironically, another poster in one of the forum articles has accurately described the situation I am now finding myself in: "It's sad that the people who most need this (new players) are the least likely to find it."

Answer (score 12):

Yes! This is a known bug, but you can still get the engine and continue with the training.

---

In the top-left corner, click the arrow for "Enable Advanced Mode", then:

- Under "Filter By Module", (purple puzzle-piece), find the tab named "Jebediah Kerman's Junkyard and Spacecraft Parts Co"

*. . . or . . .*

- Under "Filter By Manufacturer", (black factory), find the tab named "Engine"

[image]

[image]

*This thread discusses these problems in more detail:*
https://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/203608-support-3rd-tutorial-intermediate-construction-missing-hopper-vehicle/